# Xml configuration for JdbcChannelMessageStore in a Spring Boot project with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am very new to Spring Integration and would like to use a queue channel which is backed by a JdbcChannelMessageStore.
As our project uses Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA, I would like to have an `integration-context.xml` configuration where the existing data base connection is reused. However I struggle to make it work.

Unfortunately I cannot find any example projects where `JdbcChannelMessageStore` is used. Could anyone provide some good example implementations for this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S.: Here is my last `integration-context.xml` version:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <int:channel id="outgoingChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="outgoingMessageChannelStore"/>
  </int:channel>

  <bean id="dp"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${spring.datasource.password}" />
    <property name="username" value="${spring.datasource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${spring.datasource.password}" />
  </bean>


  <bean id="outgoingMessageChannelStore" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dp"/>
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="jdbcChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider"/>
    <property name="region" value="TX_TIMEOUT"/>
    <property name="usingIdCache" value="true"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" />


  <int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="jdbcChannelMessageStoreFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="@jdbcChannelMessageStore.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="@jdbcChannelMessageStore.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())" />
  </int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
</beans>
```

With this I am getting the following Exception at startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

...

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you say that you also use Spring Boot, you probably miss the fact that it auto-configure a `DataSource` bean for us. Having that `dp` bean in your config it just neglects that auto-configuration and tries to apply it everywhere you need `DataSource`, like that Hibernate auto-configuration.

What you really need is exactly opposite - you need to reuse an auto-configured `DataSource` for this Spring Integration config. Of course, if your `JdbcChannelMessageStore` is going to rely on the same data base as menitoned Spring Data JPA.

So, what you need is just remove that `dp` bean definition and use a `dataSource` name for the `<property name="dataSource"` in the `outgoingMessageChannelStore` bean definition.

Some remarks:

1. We don't need `usingIdCache` with Oracle and therefore no need in that `jdbcChannelMessageStoreFactory` to deal with the cache. And that even covered in JavaDocs:

```
     * <p>If using the provided
     * {@link org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider},
     * don't set {@link #usingIdCache}
     * to true, as the Oracle query will ignore locked rows.</p>
```

2. Try to configure Spring Integration with Java & Annotation Configuration (or even Java DSL). This way you won't be tied with a bean name (like that `dataSource`) and just will have a bean method argument injection for plain `DataSource` type and Spring container will inject for you an auto-configured bean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
I have tried with the xml configuration because the most examples for spring integration which I could find using it. This includes also your spring-integration-samples project. 
Would it be possible to have some examples from this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples)  with Java configuration?
It would be great.

Comment: What is the preferred configuration for a spring integration project?

Comment: Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl

Comment: Thanx again.
Our application is deployed in OpenShift.

Would the `JdbcChannelMessageStore` when I have 3 replicas (PODS) of my application? Where the producer is running on a single POD and receivers are on all pods?

Comment: Sounds like a different questions, but that's not for what a `QueueChannel` is about. Your question is more about a `topic` and that must be implemented fully different way...

Comment: "receivers are on all pods" - means publish-subscribe. The most famous implementation is with JMS topics: https://www.journaldev.com/9743/jms-messaging-models. Of course there are many other pub/sub impls these days around. The problem is that it is not so easy to implement yourself without messaging midleware, so there is not topic-based `MessageChannel` implementation in Spring Integration.

Comment: It is not a publish / subscribe architecture. It is more load balancing. The pods should not process the same message. 

e.g. if we have in our Q(fifo or priority): m1,m2,m3,m4
Then Pod 1 would process - m1, Pod 2 - m2, Pod 3 - m3 etc. (in parallel)

Still only one Pod, e.g. Pod 1 has a producer who can place messages on the Q

Comment: Then it is OK with the `JdbcChannelMessageStore`. Only be sure that you use a `max-messages-per-poll = "1"`. So, the messages in the store are not going to be pulled by the same instance.

Comment: Great. Thanx again for your reply